# Vue.js array disappear after update it in mutation

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex, v-for

I have a problem in my project. The project is like stackoverflow. Question/Answer. When I clicked up or down button to say this solution is useful or not, it sends to backend to increase and sends back the updated ALL solutions. Everything is ok for now. But after I updated the solutions in mutation the solutions disappear but it updates the array. It works for problem section. v-for is not used for problem section. I thought v-for and v-if may cause the problem. Okey here are the codes:

HTML

```html
<b-card
          no-body
          v-for="(solution, index) in solutionsOfProblem"
          :key="index"
        >
   <div v-if="solutionsOfProblem.length > 0">
            <b-card-body id="problem-detail-body">
              <div id="problem-detail-body-top">
                <div id="problem-detail-body-top-left">
                  <button
                    @click="upSolution(solution._id)"
                    id="up-down-buttons"
                  >
                    <b-icon-exclamation-circle-fill
                      id="up-icon"
                      variant="danger"
                      class="h2 mb-2"
                    ></b-icon-exclamation-circle-fill>
...
...
```

script.js

```js
computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user.user;
    },
    solutionToSend() {
      return this.$store.state.solutions.solutionToSend;
    },
    solutionsOfProblem() { // this shows the array of solutions
      return this.$store.state.solutions.solutionsOfProblem
    },
methods: {
upSolution(solution) { // this one trigger the action to make a post request to database
      if (this.user.name) {
        this.voteSolution.solutionId = solution
        this.voteSolution.isUpped = true
        this.$store.dispatch('solutions/voteSolutionFromDatabase', this.voteSolution)
      } else {
        this.$bvToast.toast('You need to login to vote!', {
          title: 'Error',
          autoHideDelay: 4000,
          variant: 'danger'
        })
      }
    },
}
```

mutations

```js
const solutionVoted = (state, solution) => {
  state.solutionsOfProblem = solution
}
```

state

```js
solutionsOfProblem: [],
```

actions.js - I get array from database

```js
const voteSolutionFromDatabase = ({ commit }, vote) => {
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/solution/votesolution',
    data: vote,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      commit('solutionVoted', res.data.data)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      commit('votedSolutionError', err.response)
    })
}
```

If is there any other way to update array or something is wrong with my code, I would want to hear it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A disconnect I see is that your mutation updates `state.solutionsOfProblem`, but your component's computed prop uses `state.solutions.solutionsOfProblem` (note the **`solutions`** object). Assuming that's not a typo, how are the two linked in your code? Also, please show the value of `res.data.data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright thanks to @tony19, I just realized that I was sending back the voted solution instead of the whole array.